# coffeescript acts like an ID still exists, but it does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I have removed an ID from the view, yet my coffeescript file responds as if I hadn't. When I try to apply a new ID, it does not respond to the new ID, but does still respond to the old (no longer present) ID.

I have tried `rake assets:precompile` and `rake assets:clean`, to no avail.

One clue, maybe: the coffeescript is in lists.coffee, while the view is devise/registrations/new.html.erb (not part of the Lists model). I am using lists.coffee because the action depends on functions written in that file that I would have to duplicate in users.coffee.

I do not think the problem is related to having the coffeescript in the wrong file because I have done this in other situations and it's been fine. Plus, it doesn't explain why it would respond to the ID that is no longer present.

Please help!

**Edit (code samples and further explanation):**

lists.coffee:

```
$ ->
  ...
  $('#user_settings_sex').change ->
    ...many actions...
```

devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= n.select(:sex, [['Male', 'm'],['Female', 'f'],['Decline to say', 'd']], 
  :id => "test-sex", 
  :include_blank => true, 
  :allow_blank => false, 
  :selected => params[:sex]) %>
```

Even though #user_settings_sex is not in the view, the coffeescript responds to this and only this ID. When I use user_settings_sex as the id in the coffeescript, everything works. It makes no difference which ID is used in the view (that is why the ID is currently #test-sex, because I was experimenting).

Comment: Maybe you should post the offending code so people will understand what it is you are referring to.

Comment: @dan-klasson Code added. Please let me know if there are specific additional sections that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with coffeescript: if you look at the generated html you'll see that the select element doesn't have the id `test-sex`.

This is because the `select` method takes two hashes of options: options such as `:selected` and `:include_blank` and a second hash of html options that apply to the select element. Things such as setting the id or class of that element need to be in the second hash, ie.

```
n.select(:sex,[['Male', 'm'],['Female', 'f'],['Decline to say', 'd']],
        {
          :include_blank => true, 
          :allow_blank => false, 
          :selected => params[:sex]
        }, {
          :id => "test-sex"
        })
```

Comment: Thank you!! This solved my problem immediately. As an aside, do you have a hunch why the old ID continued to be recognized by the coffeescript even after I had deleted it? Is it the case that the old behavior persists until a new ID is properly established?

Comment: The old one was just the default one - you weren't ever setting it